# Trigger function when clicking play button on <audio>

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I have my audio element:

```
<audio class='mp3audio' src='file.mp3'></audio>
```

And I want to perform a function or an action when the play button is clicked in jQuery.  I've found lots of things for creating your own custom controls, but nothing to fire when the play button is clicked.  The closest [I've found is this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onplay.asp), but then I can't use useful things like `$(this)`.

I really want something like this:

```
$('audio.mp3audio').click(function () {
    alert("you clicked play");      
});
```

But I can't find any documentation on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook to the `playing` event, so you can run the code no matter how the `audio` element is controlled; either from the play control, or manually through code. Try this:

```js
$('audio').on('playing', function() {
  console.log('playback started!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="audio" src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3" preload="auto"   controls></audio>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Where would I find the documentation on this, and the other available functions associated with the <audio> tag?

Comment: MDN has a pretty comprehensive guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events

Answer (score 1):

pass the this object in your function as

```
<audio class='mp3audio' src='file.mp3' onplay="myFunction(this)"></audio>
```

and receive it as

```
function myFunction(element){
    console.log(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this example

```js
function playBeep() {
  var sound = document.getElementById("Sound")
  sound.play();
}
```

```html
<div class="animatedButton">

  <audio id="Sound" src="https://www.soundjay.com/button/sounds/beep-07.mp3"></audio>

 
  <button id="aButton" onclick="playBeep()">
 beep
  </button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 3 ways:

In HTML:

```
<audio onplay="myScript">
```

In JavaScript:

```
var audio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
audio.onplay=function(){myScript};
```

In JavaScript, using the addEventListener() method:

```
var audio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
audio.addEventListener("play", myScript);
```

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<audio class='myaudio' ></audio>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.myaudio').on('playing', function(){
//your code
});
```

Comment: jQuery has no `onplay` method

Comment: It doesn't have a `play` method either

Comment: apologies I didnt see your answer.